# CAAnimationGroup timing

Tags: swift

This is strange to me

For the following code (where myView is a coloured UIView on the storyboard) the timing seems off.

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var myView: UIView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        let round = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "cornerRadius")
        round.fromValue = 0.0
        round.toValue = 50.0
        round.duration = 2.0
        round.beginTime = 0.0
        round.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.backwards
        round.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeIn)
        myView.layer.cornerRadius = 50.0
        
        let scaleDown = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")
        scaleDown.fromValue = 1.0
        scaleDown.toValue = 0.25
        scaleDown.beginTime = 2.0
        scaleDown.duration = 2.0
        
        
        let rotate = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
        rotate.fromValue = .pi/10.0
        rotate.toValue = 0.0
        rotate.beginTime = 4.0
        rotate.duration = 2.0

        let hideAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "hidden")
        hideAnimation.fromValue = NSNumber(value: 1)
        hideAnimation.toValue = NSNumber(value: 0)
        hideAnimation.beginTime = 4.0
        hideAnimation.duration = 2.0

        let imageGroupAnimations = CAAnimationGroup()
        imageGroupAnimations.animations = [round, scaleDown, rotate, hideAnimation]
        imageGroupAnimations.duration = 6.0
        imageGroupAnimations.repeatCount = 1
        imageGroupAnimations.beginTime = 0.0
        myView.layer.add(imageGroupAnimations, forKey: nil)
        
    }
}
```

The duration of the animation group is 6.0, so I would expect the shape to be hidden (since I expect it to be hidden from 4 to 4 + 2 (6.0) seconds.

However, the shape appears and finishes off the animation (finish rotating). I've tried using CACurrentMediaTime() in front of every beginTime - but this also doesn't have the expected result.

Expected result:

- 0-2 seconds animate corner radius change
- 2-4 seconds animate scale transformation
- 4-6 seconds animate rotation (hidden from the user)

How can I make the shape disappear from 4 - 6 seconds?

Comment: Can you describe in words what the _entire_ animation should do, second by second?

Comment: Thanks for doing that, but I don't understand the phrase "4-6 seconds animate rotation (hidden from the user)". What is the point or meaning of an animation that the user cannot see? I am still not at all understanding what is supposed to happen during seconds 4-6.

Comment: Do you mean it should vanish suddenly, then reappear suddenly two seconds later in a rotated position? If so, the "vanish" and "reappear" animation durations would need be _very very short_, right?

Comment: Also I do not understand how the `fromValue` of the rotation can be `.pi/10.0`. The `fromValue` needs to be where we actually are, which is `0` — we are at no rotation when we start.

Comment: I gave an answer, but I still find your requirements incoherent...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show fade-out effect on view, use

```
let hideAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
```

Instead of

```
let hideAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "hidden") //bad!
```

---

If you don't want animation to reset your values after finish, simply add

```
imageGroupAnimations.fillMode = .forwards
imageGroupAnimations.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
```

to your `CAAnimationGroup`

Comment: How can I make the shape disappear from 4 - 6 seconds? Not animated. Disappear (isHidden) from 4-6 seconds of the animation?

Answer (score 0):

The `duration` is not how long something *stays true* — it is how long it takes to *perform a change*.

So if you want the view to vanish suddenly, obviously you need to change `hideAnimation.duration = 2.0` so that the duration is very short, say, `0.01`.

This is a `hideAnimation` where the view turns invisible suddenly at the 4th second of the animation, and stays invisible until the end of the animation:

```
    let hideAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "hidden")
    hideAnimation.fromValue = false
    hideAnimation.toValue = true
    hideAnimation.beginTime = 4.0
    hideAnimation.duration = 0.01
    hideAnimation.fillMode = .forwards
```

But I did not make any other changes because I still do not understand the complete effect that you want...